# Multiply matrices in cell array Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of `cell(1, n)` called `A`, with each cell entry containing a matrix of `mxn`. So, in effect, my cell array contains `n` matrices of size `mxn`.

I then have another cell array called `B`, with `n` `pxm` matrices stored in it.

What I need to do is multiply the two against each other, as in: `A[1] * B[1]`, `A[2] * B[2]`, ..., `A[n] * B[n]`. I then need to store the results as individual matrices of their own, and sum them up.

The matrices are conformal for multiplication, but because cell array `B` contains less rows than cell array `A`, when I use `cellfun(@times A, B, 'UniformOutput', true)` I get an `unequal matrices` error.

This seems to indicate that `cellfun` can only multiply individual cells when the matrices have equal numbers of rows and columns.

Now, I could perform this by using various loops, or by calling `cell2mat` and `mat2cell`, and so on. I could also just store everything as a matrix array rather than using cells... but - I would prefer to use cells.

So - my question is: Is there a good way of doing this using only `cellfun`? I have tried various combinations of argument inputs already - but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with `cellfun`, just define your own anonymous function:

```
C = cellfun(@(a,b) a*b, A, B, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Now, as you posed the question, you cannot multiply A*B, because the inner dimensions don't agree. Instead, I tested this with B*A, where the dimensions do agree: p=1, m=3, n=3.

```
A = {eye(3), rand(3), magic(3)};
B = {[1 2 3], [3 5 1], [7 8 8]};

C = cellfun(@(a,b) b*a, A, B, 'UniformOutput', 0);

Cmat = cat(3, C{:});
S = sum(Cmat, 3);
```

The sum is done by concatenating each array of `C` over a third dimension then summing over it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the arguments need to be of the same size. From `help cellfun`:

> A = cellfun(FUN, B, C, ...) evaluates FUN using the contents of the
>       cells of cell arrays B, C, ... as input arguments.  The (I,J,...)th
>       element of A is equal to FUN(B{I,J,...}, C{I,J,...}, ...).  B, C, ...
>       must all have the same size.

So either use loops, or remove the extra elements from the cell with a larger number of elements before you call `cellfun`:

```
% assuming B has more elements than A
B(numel(A)+1:end) = [];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant delete the extra columns in the matrices. The matrices in the cells were uneven i.e. there were not of same dimension but were conformal for multiplication,  both cell arrays have save number of elements just the matrices are different and cellfun(@times ,,,,) did not allow the multiplication to take place. Thanks very much for the reply regardless :)